# NameError: name 'Rule' is not defined in python scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have the following script for crawling a website recursively:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner

class GivenSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/",
#        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
 #       "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/'), callback=parse, follow=True),)

    def parse(self, response):
        select = Selector(response)
        titles = select.xpath('//a[@class="listinglink"]/text()').extract()
        print ' [*] Start crawling at %s ' % response.url
        for title in titles:
            print '\t %s' % title


#configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
runner = CrawlerRunner()

d = runner.crawl(GivenSpider)
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()
```

When I invoke it:

```
$ python spide.py
NameError: name 'Rule' is not defined
```

Comment: You never imported `Rule`?

Comment: well, Rule isn't defined in the code anywhere so what's the question?

Comment: How can I use Rule to recursivly scan the whole site?

Comment: @MLSC reading the documentation would be a good start. It's worth it I heard.

Comment: Thank you, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go by the documentation and search for the word Rule, you'll find this:

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.20/topics/spiders.html?highlight=rule#crawling-rules

As you didn't import anything, it is clear that Rule isn't being defined.

```
 class scrapy.contrib.spiders.Rule(link_extractor, callback=None, cb_kwargs=None, follow=None, process_links=None, process_request=None)
```

So, in theory, you should be able to import the `Rule` class with `from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule`

Answer (score 1):

Loïc Faure-Lacroix is right. But in the current version of Scrapy (1.6), you need to import `Rule` from `scrapy.spiders` like this:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
```

[See documentation for more information](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.6/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules)