# NameError: name 'Rule' is not defined but i did import Rule library

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am making a crawler with scrapy, and I cant use the word Rule, but I did import this.

stack_crawler.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item

from stack.items import StackItem


class StackCrawlerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'stack_crawler'
    allowed_domains = ['stackoverflow.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.stackoverflow.com/']

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'Items/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )
```

...

when I execute 
So i get this error message in shell "NameError: name 'Rule' is not defined"

can anyone help me?

```
(ENV) lucas@lucas-TWS:~/ENV/stack$ scrapy crawl stack_crawler
/home/lucas/ENV/stack/stack/spiders/stack_crawler.py:3: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.linkextractors` is deprecated, use `scrapy.linkextractors` instead
  from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
/home/lucas/ENV/stack/stack/spiders/stack_crawler.py:4: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.spiders` is deprecated, use `scrapy.spiders` instead
  from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
/home/lucas/ENV/stack/stack/spiders/stack_crawler.py:5: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml` is deprecated, use `scrapy.linkextractors.sgml` instead
  from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
/home/lucas/ENV/stack/stack/spiders/stack_crawler.py:18: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: SgmlLinkExtractor is deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Please use scrapy.linkextractors.LinkExtractor
  Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'questions\?page=[0-9]&sort=newest'),
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 149, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 249, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 137, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 336, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 61, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 47, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/lucas/ENV/stack/stack/spiders/stack_spider.py", line 7, in <module>
    class StackSpider(Spider):
  File "/home/lucas/ENV/stack/stack/spiders/stack_spider.py", line 15, in StackSpider
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'questions\?page=[0-2]&sort=newest'),
NameError: name 'Rule' is not defined
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NameError: name 'Rule' is not defined in python scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941528/nameerror-name-rule-is-not-defined-in-python-scrapy)

Comment: You're importing `Rule`, so this error should not happen.  Are you sure this is the exact code you're running?  Can you show us how you're running this code from the shell?

Comment: (ENV) lucas@lucas-TWS:~/ENV/stack$ scrapy crawl stack_crawler

Comment: @clearshot66 It's not necessarily duplicated.  Here, he has already imported 'Rule'.

Comment: But may have been missing other import

Comment: The error is coming from `stack_spider.py`, but the code you showed us is `stack_crawler.py`.